# SQL - How to order by how close a character is to the beginning of the word

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am a beginner to web development and I would like to know if there is a way to order my query by how close a character is to the beginning of the word.

By this I mean:

Let's say that I have a query with all the entries sharing an 'a'
I want to order the entries by how close the 'a' is at the beginning of the word.

So if this was my query:

```
´walk´
´Andrew´
´leaf´
´umbrella´
´michael´
```

It would be ordered like this:

```
´Andrew´
´walk´
´leaf´
´michael´
´umbrella´
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are there any words that do not contain `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way by first finding the position of the substring (`a`) and then ordering by that position (updated to exclude words with no `a`):

```
select word, position('a' in word) as position
from words
having position > 0
order by position asc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15350a/2

Comment: No need to select the `position` expression, just order by it.

Comment: true, was just for information purposes, that, and to use as an alias for the order by.

Comment: good point, will update the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
select   word
from     words
order by ifnull(nullif(position('a' in word),0),999999999999)
```

| word |
| --- |
| Andrew |
| walk |
| leaf |
| michael |
| umbrella |
| bcdefg |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4330c30ef10da5e30e3222243036ec3)